# rails friendly_id bad request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest, friendly-id

I'm new to rails and currently involved in an internship and I was assigned to use the friendly_id gem for my tournament class, this is part of the code in it:

```
class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :url_id
  ...
end
```

I don't use a slug since I have a `url_id` attribute that stores my desired url and when I try with the old `.../tournaments/1` everything's all good but with `.../tournaments/example` I get "example is not a valid value for id" with code 103, status 400. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2):

You have to update your controller for `Tournaments` so that it uses `friendly.find` method instead of the `find`.

```
# Change this:
Tournament.find(params[:id])

# to
Tournament.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: The `tournaments_controller.rb` file is empty

Comment: Well, look into your logs and find the exact line where that `example is not a valid value for id` error is being raised and you'll find your file.

Comment: Started GET "/api/tournaments/example" for ::1 at 2016-08-09 11:48:27 +0300
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
Processing by TournamentsController#show as API_JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"example"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 7ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

I don't get it, is it handled by `tournaments_controller.rb` ?

Comment: That `example is not a valid value for id` message I got from using the open http-requester pluggin in firefox.

Comment: Apparently your `tournaments_controller.rb` file has something. At the very least it got to have `respond_with` call. Paste your entire file contents here please...

Comment: All it has is 

     `class TournamentsController < ApplicationController
     end`

so does each controller file for the other models, I don't understand, is there some kind of workaround to allow such empty controllers, because I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Also when I added a show method in the tournament controller and pasted your code plus the json rendering, I managed to make it working but my tutor said that's not how it should be done.

Comment: From what I understand, we're using the gem jsonapi-resources and we use its method show, `class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include JSONAPI::ActsAsResourceController
end`